# How to use Id in URL path.

Tags: c#, .net, url, xamarin

Goal: Get the correct Id from table and use this in my URL path.

I am currently making an application. In the application there is supposed to be showed a list where the user can choose one element. Choosing this element sends the user to a new page, where one can update some information. My problem is at the updating process. I am not able to get the correct Id and use this in the URL path of my PUT request.

My PUT request from the dataService.cs file:

```
public async Task UpdateData(Post item)
        {
            const string Url = "http://localhost:5000/checklist/{0}";
            var uri = new Uri(string.Format(Url, item.Id));
            var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
            var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = await _client.PutAsync(uri, content); 
        }
```

The PUT request is triggered from this function in the Checklist.cs file:

```
async void Button_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Post newItem = new Post
        {
            DeviationDescription = DeviationDescript.ToString(),
            Date = DateTime.Now
        };
        dataService ds = new dataService();
        await ds.UpdateData(newItem);
        //RefreshData();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't set Id in `newPost`.

You have to set it from client, you can use `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()` to have a new id every time.

Comment: Problem is, I already have an Id. However I am not able to get this Id. Any idea of how to get the current id, instead of making a new one every time?

Comment: Where is the Id? you create a new Post every time. You can set it, like you set DeviationDescription.